# Can I include individuals with a single data point in a growth curve model?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, growth-model

I read that one of the main advantages of using a growth curve model is that it can handle missing data. Some of the participants in my study have data for only one time point, while most have data across several time points.

Can I include the former in a linear growth curve model? If yes, how will individual trajectories be computed for individuals with a single time point?

Comment: you can but shouldn't

Comment: In a parametric individuals with only one data point still contribute information about the general *level*, but not about the shape of the curve, so you can include them.

Comment: @Aksakal would you mind elaborating on why this isn't a good idea?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen My concern then, is how the random slope will be generated for these individuals

Comment: You didn't specify a model, so I thought about a random intercept. For a random slope, the model would just give the expected slope for that model. It shouldn't be taken too serious by itself,but it does no damage to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include individuals with only one observation in a growth model. This individuals will not contribute information about the shape of the growth curve (such as slope), only about the general level. That could still be useful information though, and omitting data could bias the results.

I will illustrate using a data set from the R package `nlme`:

```r
mydat <- nlme::Oxboys

ind1 <- c( (0:6)*9 + 1, 64:234)
mydat1 <- mydat[ind1, ]
```

The data frame `mydat1` have eliminated all but one of the observations from a subset of the `Subject`s. First let us look at a plot:

[image: lineplot of the Oxboys data]

Then we fit simple linear growth models on the complete and subsetted data:

```r
library(ggplot2, lme4)
mod <- lme4::lmer( height ~ age  +  (1 | Subject), data=mydat)
mod1 <- lme4::lmer( height ~ age  +  (1 | Subject), data=mydat1)

### Predict with model for reduced data set,  but for the full data:

newvals <-  predict(mod1, newdata=mydat)

newframe <- data.frame(mydat, newvals)
```

The fitted models are quite similar:

```r
 summary(mod)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: height ~ age + (1 | Subject)
   Data: mydat

REML criterion at convergence: 940

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.1857 -0.6350 -0.1339  0.6252  2.5357 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 65.555   8.097   
 Residual              1.718   1.311   
Number of obs: 234, groups:  Subject, 26

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 149.3717     1.5902   93.93
age           6.5239     0.1325   49.23

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr)
age -0.002
  summary(mod1)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: height ~ age + (1 | Subject)
   Data: mydat1

REML criterion at convergence: 732.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0938 -0.5864 -0.1144  0.5203  2.4063 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 62.238   7.889   
 Residual              1.703   1.305   
Number of obs: 178, groups:  Subject, 26

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 149.4966     1.5550   96.14
age           6.7146     0.1542   43.55

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr)
age 0.025
```

Finally, have a look at the predictions for the reduced data model, but calculated for the full data set:

[image: line plot of predictions]

Since this is a linear model with random intercepts only, we see of course parallel lines. But everything works exactly the same way if we include a random slope, as we can with

```r
mod.rs <- lme4::lmer( height ~ age  +  (1 + age | Subject), data=mydat)
```

but I leave that as an exercise.  And, this was a linear growth model, but the same will apply for a nonlinear growth model.